# Why does macOS Terminal add extraneous stuff to end of command line for popd and dirs commands?

Tags: macos, bash

Using Mojave 10.14.4. When I type the command `popd` in Terminal, as soon as I press Return, the following is added to the end of my command:

`;2D;2D;2D;2Ddopp`

The pop command works, but I also get this output:

```
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2Ddopp: command not found
```

UPDATE 2019-05-17 07:24:
Still trying to resolve this issue. It happens with many commands. The number of `2Ds` added is equal to the number of characters in the command argument and the final characters added (`dopp` in above example) are a re-arrangement of the letters of the argument. See the example below:

```
grep foobar;2D;2D;2D;2D;2D;2Dfooter
^C
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2D: command not found
-bash: 2Dfooter: command not found
```

So this seems to be related to some sort of spell check.

Also, if I switch Users, this does not happen in Terminal.app of other user.

Anyone know what is going on and how I can fix it?

---

In response to @jvb's comment below:

Output from his suggested echo and unset commands:

```
TIGER:temp jim$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$
TIGER:temp jim$ unset $PS1
-bash: unset: `\h:\W': not a valid identifier
-bash: unset: `\u\$': not a valid identifier
TIGER:temp jim$
```

Problem persists after the unset command.

---

Note that problem was found and corrected. See reply below.

Comment: Do you have any interesting escape sequences in your prompt (`echo $PS1`)? Does it still happen if you unset $PS1?

Comment: @jvb. I'll put output for echo and unset commands in a reply below (because I do not know how to put a block of code in a comment). I am new to bash shell so not sure what this output means.

Comment: @jvb. Thanks for your help. I found the problem. I have TypeIt4Me installed and that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I have TypeIt4Me installed and that was causing the problem. I don't know if this is specific to Mojave or also is a problem in other versions of macOS.

UPDATE 2019-05-21: TypeIt4Me support responded to my report of this issue. It turns out you can tell TypeIt4Me to ignore specific apps. Go into TypeIt4Me's Preferences, click the Special tab, and add the app you want TypeIt4Me to ignore. Great! Solved my problem.

UPDATE 2019-05-24 09:26. The folks at TypeIt4Me support continued to look at the cause of my issue. This morning I got yet another email telling me they had figured it out. Under Preferences|AutoCorrect, I had the box labeled "Correct typos with AppleSpell" checked and this was causing the problem. Since I want to keep this setting, I left Terminal in the list of apps the TypeIt4Me should ignore. Hat tip to Guy and Riccardo at TypeIt4Me for great technical support!